# Website favicon not appearing on iPhone 6 (Home Screen)

Tags: html, ios, iphone, favicon

I'm using the syntax as generated by *realfavicongenerator.net* to specify all favicon sizes, yet for some reason the icon is not displaying on iPhone 6 (3 separate devices, browser cached cleared). It is showing a screenshot of the site instead. Any ideas why this is happening?

I've looked at every article I could find on the latest syntax (including the article by Mathias Bynens; I had that exact syntax originally, with the same problem, before I tried realfavicongenerator). iPhone 6 should be using the sizes specified. Running the [favicon checker](http://realfavicongenerator.net/favicon_checker?site=troubadourgoods.com&ignore_root_issues=on) shows green across the board. I've triple checked the that all the links in the source are correct.

```
<!--Favicon and Apple Touch Icons-->
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="57x57" href="//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0171/0160/t/3/assets/apple-touch-icon-57x57.png?18609">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="60x60" href="//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0171/0160/t/3/assets/apple-touch-icon-60x60.png?18609">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="72x72" href="//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0171/0160/t/3/assets/apple-touch-icon-72x72.png?18609">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="76x76" href="//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0171/0160/t/3/assets/apple-touch-icon-76x76.png?18609">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="114x114" href="//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0171/0160/t/3/assets/apple-touch-icon-114x114.png?18609">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="120x120" href="//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0171/0160/t/3/assets/apple-touch-icon-120x120.png?18609">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="144x144" href="//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0171/0160/t/3/assets/apple-touch-icon-144x144.png?18609">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="152x152" href="//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0171/0160/t/3/assets/apple-touch-icon-152x152.png?18609">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0171/0160/t/3/assets/apple-touch-icon-180x180.png?18609">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0171/0160/t/3/assets/favicon-32x32.png?18609" sizes="32x32">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0171/0160/t/3/assets/favicon-192x192.png?18609" sizes="192x192">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0171/0160/t/3/assets/favicon-160x160.png?18609" sizes="160x160">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0171/0160/t/3/assets/favicon-96x96.png?18609" sizes="96x96">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0171/0160/t/3/assets/favicon-16x16.png?18609" sizes="16x16">
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0171/0160/t/3/assets/favicon.ico?18609">
```

(The website is in Shopify- perhaps that is related to the issue)

[image: Home screen on iPhone 6]

UPDATE:
The icon does appear when Add Bookmark is used, but not Add to Home Screen. I've changed the generated protocol-relative URLs (//cdn...) on the site to start with HTTPs to test whether this might be the issue, and that does not seem to have fixed it (an iPhone 6 user who says he cleared his cache still does not see it).

Comment: Did you ever figure this one out? My testing seems to indicate that Add to Home Screen on IOS only works if it is HTTP protocol.

Comment: Interesting...unfortunately I never did figure out why this was occurring or how to fix it.

Comment: same issue here, do you any recent updates @jwinn?

Answer (score 0):

Old question but here is the answer. Since Shopify uses its own (.liquid) file types, it looks for links via its own syntax. Upload each favicon file to your assets folder and then change your absolute links to the following:

```
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="57x57" href="{{ 'apple-touch-icon-57x57.png' | asset_url }}">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="60x60" href="{{ 'apple-touch-icon-60x60.png' | asset_url }}">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="72x72" href="{{ 'apple-touch-icon-72x72.png' | asset_url }}">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="76x76" href="{{ 'apple-touch-icon-76x76.png' | asset_url }}">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="114x114" href="{{ 'apple-touch-icon-114x114.png' | asset_url }}">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="120x120" href="{{ 'apple-touch-icon-120x120.png' | asset_url }}">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="144x144" href="{{ 'apple-touch-icon-144x144.png' | asset_url }}">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="152x152" href="{{ 'apple-touch-icon-152x152.png' | asset_url }}">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="{{ 'apple-touch-icon-180x180.png' | asset_url }}">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="{{ 'favicon-32x32.png' | asset_url }}" sizes="32x32">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="{{ 'favicon-192x192.png' | asset_url }}" sizes="192x192">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="{{ 'favicon-160x160.png' | asset_url }}" sizes="160x160">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="{{ 'favicon-96x96.png' | asset_url }}" sizes="96x96">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="{{ 'favicon-16x16.png' | asset_url }}" sizes="16x16">
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="{{ 'favicon.ico' | asset_url }}">
```

Comment: That wasn't the issue. The URLs in the post were indeed generated using the liquid asset_url.

Comment: Well the above syntax generates a proper icon on iPhone 6. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem and tried about 100 different things to solve it. Favicon was showing on ipad (homescreen + bookmark), android, IE, chrome (windows + apple), safari (desktop), but not on iphone 6 safari.

The issue turned out to be using relative instead of absolute links.

When I replaced the favicon img hrefs from `href="/favicon.png"` to `href="https://website.com/favicon.png"` the problem was solved. It doesn't make sense why it would be so, but that solved the problem...

Favicon files were in my root site directory btw.